# Can a viewcontroller access the identifier of an incoming segue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

Can a viewcontroller access the identifier of the segue that was used to transition to it? For example, I transition from viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B using a segue with the identifier "mySegue". Is there anyway for viewcontroller B to get the segue's identifier?

Comment: Seems like you could override `-prepareForSegue:sender:` and store it.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a default property I can access without having to store it as a custom variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a property. This kind of thing should be handled via the calling VC's prepareForSegue:sender method (as said in the comments) and then assigning a custom property to denote where it came from, etc.