# content of the viewcontroller changes according to the segue identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have multiple segues from one viewController to another viewController. In the destinationViewController I have Label and Text View that changes according to the identifier. Of course, I can manage this without identifiers and just copy and paste viewControllers, and make my storyboard even bigger, write more code. But I want to learn to write good code. So, please help me to manage the issue.

I have such picture in my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

So, each button has its own identifier. I don't pass any data from ABOUT viewController, I just change the data inside History View Controller. That is why I need to solve the problem without using prepareForSegue function (because again I don't pass any data). And if I use prepareForSegue, then I will need to manage protocols, and that means more code.

Comment: You need to either pass data from the first view controller to the second one or create three separate view controllers in the storyboard to segue to.

Comment: How the second controller recognize what data need to show? You can't doing this w/o passing some data.

Comment: @AndrewVeresov the only data that is passed is identifier

Comment: @Anuar Maratkhan So what's problem? You got identifier, check this identifier in History VC and make changes based on the identifier name.

Comment: @AndrewVeresov but the changes are made in History VC, and prepareForSegue method is being called in About VC, so I first need to pass Outlets of label and text view there, which seems difficult for me

Comment: You said previously said "I don't pass any data from ABOUT viewController, I just change the data inside History View Controller". So just in view did load check the identifier 
switch(indet) {
}

Comment: @AndrewVeresov that is what I am looking for! Can you please answer the question showing how to do it?

Comment: @Anuar Maratkhan ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the identifier as a parameter from the calling ViewController in prepareForSegue.

See also: [Can a viewcontroller access the identifier of an incoming segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629399/can-a-viewcontroller-access-the-identifier-of-an-incoming-segue)

Answer (score 0):

it's a fast example how you can do it.

```
//specify enum
    enum SegueType: Int {
        case history, about, howto
    }

    class AboutVC: UIViewController {

        //button pressing
       @IBAction func didPressHistoryButton(sender: UIButton) {
                let segueIdent = "show.History"
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdent, sender: SegueType.history)
        }

        // in your about vc
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HistoryVC {
                destinationVC.segueType = sender as? SegueType
            }
        }
    }

    // in your history vc
    class HistoryVC: UIViewController {

        var segueType: SegueType? = nil

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

                switch segueType! {
                case SegueType.history:
                    // segue from history button
                    break
                case SegueType.about:
                    // segue from about button
                    break
                case  SegueType.howto:
                // segue from how to button\
                    break
                default:
                    // segue from ???
                    break
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've got an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'SegueType' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'"

Comment: I forgot to say, I use Swift 2.3

Comment: So edit your question to show the new code at the bottom, along with telling us which line is giving you an error.